# SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8114Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

Here I am trying to export the data into.csv and the file is getting generated in the specific folder. But without header. Tried to declare `@columnHeader` getting below error:

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to  bigint.
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to resolve column level collations

Please do needfull

```sql
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateCDR]
   AS
   Begin
   DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(8000)
   DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR(125)
   DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(125)
   DECLARE @todaysDateFormatted VARCHAR(30)
   DECLARE @ServerName varchar(50)

   -- generate the dynamic file name based on the date and time
   SELECT @todaysDateFormatted = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + '_' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) 
   AS VARCHAR) + '_' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '_' + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, 
   GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
   -- ALTER the file name
   SET    @fileName ='Tansactions_'+  @todaysDateFormatted + '.csv';

   SET @ServerName = 'xxxxxxxx';

   DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000)

   DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(8000)
   SELECT @columnHeader = 
 
'''RecordID'',''MSISDN'',''Amount'',''ReferenceID'',''SessionID'',''Action'',''RequestDate'',''ResponseDate'',''StatusID'',''Channel'''

   Select @cmd = 'BCP '+
   '"Select '+ @columnHeader +' UNION ALL SELECT TOP 100 
   RecordID,MSISDN,Amount,ReferenceID,SessionID,Action,RequestDate,ResponseDate,StatusID,Channel From 
   [databasename].[dbo].[tablename]"'
    + ' QUERYOUT C:\TransactionsData\' +@fileName +' '+ '/c /t"|" /T'+@ServerName
   PRINT @cmd
   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
   PRINT @cmd


   End
```

Comment: you need to convert  the following columns `RecordID,MSISDN,Amount,ReferenceID,SessionID,Action,RequestDate,ResponseDate,StatusID,Channel` to varchar before union with `@columnHeader`

Comment: Can you just help me with converting all column into varchar  I am very new to it.

Comment: Apart from that you're missing out the length, [a *really* bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), you clearly already know how to cast/convert a value to a `varchar`, @sowmyasirsi ; there are multiple example of you doing it in your query.

Comment: @Larnu Why do people insist on building and running cmd batch files from T-SQL, when Powershell does the job much better?

Comment: I believe it's what's known as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), @Charlieface . Considering that Agent has the ability to run Powershell scripts natively too (provided you aren't on SQL Server on Linux), most of the time I *don't* see the need for messy calls to `bcp` via `xp_cmdshell` (but then, SQL Server on Linux doesn't support `xp_cmdshell` either, so the point there is moot :) )